# Using input stream iterator with array

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, inputstream, std

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_NAME_LENGTH=100;

int main()
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

    cout<<"Introduce yourself\n";

    istream_iterator<char> eos;
    istream_iterator<char> isi(cin);

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_NAME_LENGTH; i++)
    {   
        if(isi == eos) 
        {
            name[i]=0; //Breakpoint is set here.
            break;
        }
        name[i] = *isi;
        isi++;
    }
    cout<<"Hi "<<name<<endl;

    system("pause");


}
```

When I type a name and press enter, this program still yields only a command prompt. After debugging, it turned out that the "if" is never reached; It seems to be that the end of stream (eos) is unreachable.

1. Why the condition inside the "if" is always false?
2. What is the simpliest way to fix my problem?

Comment: Input: `"Hello" {ENTER} {CTRL-Z}` Output: `"Hi Hello"`. No problem there.

Comment: @chris CTRL-Z, that's what I needed!You can turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Note that `istream_iterator` skips whitespace characters. If `John Doe` introduces himself, you'll call him `JohnDoe`. You can use `istreambuf_iterator` to preserve the input as-is.

Comment: @jork You've just answered my next question :)

Comment: @steffen, It is, with the default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is satisfied when the end of file is reached, but the console has no natural EOF, so you need to tell it explicitly where the end is. You can enter the EOF character to the console by pressing ctrl+z in Windows or ctrl+d in Unix. Here's a sample run that works:

**Input**

```
Chris
^Z
```

**Output**

```
Hi Chris
```